# url rotator showing unique hits

Tags: php, mysql, url, rotator

I want to create an URL rotator page in php that shows each URL once for each visitor,  in other words, each url in the rotator will get unique hits only, and if the same visitor (ip) has already seen all urls in the rotator, it will show a default URL, this default URL will be shown only when all links have been shown to that visitor.

urls might be stored in .db file or in MySQL data base.

it would be better if you can show me how to do that using visitor ip and not cookies.

Comment: I only know how to create url rotator in random order or a specifique order from here: stackoverflow.com/questions/10351958/url-rotator-in-specifique-order

Comment: still no one whant to answer?

Comment: You still have not shown that you have put any effort into actually solving your problem.  There are pretty much an infinite number of ways to solve this problem. Try one and ask questions here when you run into specific implementation problems.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem with using visitor IP is that 1) can potentially change from session to session and more pertinent 2) multiple users behind a firewall/proxy will show up as a single IP. Using cookies (or an equivalent, locally stored marker) is the only way to effectively achieve what you are looking to do.

Is there a reason why you are not wanting to use cookies?

Comment: I just think if a visitor clears his cookies then he will see the same url again, but with ips it doesn't matter if he does that or not

Comment: Well, yes, that is a risk you have to accept (also users using Incognito modes, etc... will also impacted cookie use). So, short of storing some other kind of marker on the clients computer that you can act against (via Java, Flash, etc...), you really have no way to force a user to see content in the manner that you are seeking.

Going by IP is *the least reliable approach* you can go with. IPs are general transitory and users may have (in fact are likely to have) a different IP address every time they go online or be collected together under a single IP address (behind a firewall).

Comment: I get that, but I still prefer IP than cookies